# PHP Session wrapper

Tags: php, session

I wrote a static Session class that can obviously 'set, get, start but does not destroy' temp user sessions, meaning i have to start a session on each page to be able to destroy it, which make no sense in programming standards.any better way to this approach?

```
class sessionWrapper {
    private static $_sessionStarted = false;
    public static function start() {
        if(self::$_sessionStarted == false) {
            session_start();
            self::$_sessionStarted = true;
        }
    }

    public static function set($key, $value) {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }

    public static function get($key) {
        if(isset($_SESSION[$key])) {
            return $_SESSION[$key];
        } else {
                return false;
        }
    }

    public static function destroy() {
        if(self::$_sessionStarted == true) {
            session_destroy();
            header('Location: $url');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with `on each page`? Because a session must be started on each request thats how sessions work.

Comment: I mean i cannot start it *once on my header template and have it work throughout the entire site...

Comment: If the `header template` is always included, then it should work. What are you doing in the `header`? The class you show is fine, if used correct.

Comment: can you please assist with an example that demonstrates getting the $_SESSION['user_id'] set once the user logs in and only place it once in the headerTemp...

Comment: Not really. I can help on not working code, but wont write it for you. But currently you are showing working code here. Maybe test some logic and if you get stuck, open a new question with this new code.